# Synchronizing Position of FileStream and StreamReader

Tags: c#, pdf, io, filestream

I am trying to write a program that will parse PDF files. From what I've read so far, PDF files are a combination of text data and binary data.

For example, within the PDF, there are "stream" objects which start with the word `stream(newline)`, then contain the necessary binary data, and then end with the word `endstream(newline)`

Here is an example:

```
677 0 obj
<</Length 2821
/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
xœ…ZÛnG}÷WLô’, Oú~AÙ 6—AGbKœ5Éf†¦õ™ù£=M™dŸÖX›‡ÄÏô¥êTÕ©j¸yLœ“·¡5J»æfõæÇ_T#M+ðOssÿæ‡«÷ëë57ÿ}óï›7nÞH[c¼£o~Ø»©Oûñúª„FÝ-yùÆýöv“VP9Ù¯ª5çu*1!´R‡j±iØ¬ú48­}k…¶ŒûeìvwC?•71B´2hÁÈ~WBpYeUµØôØÏåÑŒµ­¦Zh¸/!Þ´ÿbÈºßNis_Ê‹¯1²u'ÜÕÉ¼miÞ³óþp†ÞtŸRs×éúª™º~Õ¼»-.Þ\Í§_¾[\E„VœWùã¾9¬»ù]³JÝØüÖ6«ïMãí¦{:-û¡ë§´MÝþËu³î6÷M¿›‡/ý]7§U»°¾‹²U—S’o3§œ”A›4ÏäZi=h"
Ãëþn]E¨V™(U‘IùÖŽ0wÃ~d2)£¡w;ö»‡©äœÒ­v±:ÿ<”ìÏ¨Ík§ÒÎã'_üaøœÆÝPËhÑ*ªã3áLh«OÞ•q?Œó˜¦òvÙ@ÇX½ŸXë@ó"6·iî·ijº]3Œ«´L_¯^˜þ;ø¶yjºÍ¡{š–ñFtÿyhvÃü¼üÔôÓ´OÍý8l˜¶Ùö»~‡¦w‹!n.Œÿ;!Fö»Õ°¿ƒ7O?5·ûùŸÅï„/˜ü~Wf2©Tk£Ê¡D<m”Ùò%ˆè"½k~® ë4¥n…õ–Qç[‘m«•1Œ\•[ªèZc£bŒ@DW­4¦²âf—÷ëvUzU^ÅW(1pC1&/ÔÍû‘k2åK$QÞ
äØ(Íkžˆj£¸õÂy‘!Öë‚š¦qÝ=–V…)àHïø4ìÉ“fµŠ1]NFßjªuÆþa=—©Ti‹_fØï ù·Ü j¯ÉW[ƒ¤Dèïg
\m\®–Õ’Xð©ùØJ!"ƒæy!Ny   †Â0ð°NÄPÛi_3š¶…áÌkF;»ÒºK>˜úy†7©¶À™ZhÆÝ&$ºTÅ$2‹aXGŽeœ°ŒxR2ÂµQ8Ï ¹ƒà)}£ŒUÃ~üÅðšÓœÞvoóJgðÉ™úSÖl‡~.K¢ÖÁãÂ·/§Q.¬s‘÷(‡»Õ?ï×ßQÌzœ]W†ÿXÑÀj©j“—nÁZtå°€ê\mºrÊc7¾]âê‚¸d¶‰VhíeÐIUýT"] 2F~$À˜9OtzÊT©dÈ2Ä1¬'Ê¸51VÊÛÈ0
¹ìÛÇ<mQç«}kJíA·^Cé&íº¢––­UºÚŒ#‹’c=c¨¼ÁÐ­
ªÚmÚ?>¦‘ôwÖ­Á™j)ª§·SVTÛÍ\OMÈB>ÊoÉ„LïXm5=¦îÓ“ çŠ²ÜtÍý>—£,žWý®Û,ê‹Ð?—”«ÿ¤¹JBÀ8í©–h4KÈ1yìHŠIga²œƒJPˆTMBîÐ"ƒ²Í(ÁÙB Z*Ë}jÌ4ì–£¡ÒŸRÎf¡8   ËîÌÔÐ*zÆŒ   Öå¶+÷"¾²)   $ƒZ(¤ª,Z¥(\Å˜¯-cyt+Á²¶ ýNÜ0!^
Ò©«\äƒñªÐ©¥ÍæBxuì«Ð1MÍéëÉ*-êƒ´wQ¨¿¦ãg«´ÝcZ-vqFÇB›â‹¾8ŒÃîá:+âÝò6Puæþ:²¢ ô    ‰®¤¬ÜÂA`ZgRW4¿R=>{™?áJvº-Q×å‡ó”ŠÐ,ê“0SJe²×(e‰šAµD²2<ƒnÓ]·'1n Y<Šã`tÖ±¨üèP-£hC“S¬AÕã£çnjÍÚæLJa/¤L_æ±Ž‰ŠTœD4(­MhwHŸÓdÞ¹„`W*Iˆ(BÁ m—›uR«?G(vÂ}¤ˆoTu$Ú-d%XŸº¨¹Öæø%Ðã0M=„å.êr9Â’qÕ©"!óP—r zHëcoC˜‰„œ#„÷ÕÁO‰aÁÓ…ìœT¸ÈK´?ZC2†CNÇPºÂäüP¢‚D`¢s 3á­2yVp”¢zÉæ1A«¾&‡ú°ŒADSÉ*V¨W a(QÇnt´(^½r=#sÛQ[ ê]uÓðliÀ_\>¾²Yî[…Õ•-™(gÿgÂœd¹ÍßÁÜ
DÊºß.–!0¼T„¿òñÞ5ó·é¹24ÏÍÐ¹½kr@4È•Û©»œÁPxÆÕòòº˜g^ý   Ø@<‘‚7†q[j†¤ËÁ”‰Ë˜1mÊ W(Ðp‚a]¹›½ÁLÅõãa¿éÆ~~j)k {mý‰‰óë<ª!L)-“¬-1¯‡=ºwÊ*ÐJžÏÆYÄÌš†
ñDIEäddÈj?(g9ç+3°|Šh=¬¯ýÒ}Zê°µ*fÑy–w;¥ñs7÷Ã®9N_Á§ØÒôÛÇaœ»Ý¼LQÎ©ÿ ¦RÊÜ¡¢ÈèñåÄÅç–IjÆUè_´(‘1œ”mÔÎ2æ8q¡'Œ,€µ·Õá§¹Ûf~®êì¤cuƒ‹TnÉÑÐ!T·¨†âÆ"•! 1(Ïª¾Ÿ*Oc
ÃŽóÐWæW”åN3{    Ý#¦î·¤þX«4qœÍ%dkŒh} Ã…¨Fá(.&r0äyÐK1•¼¯®V•tåpêœ…ùD¨UŸy¶¢PÕÀB‚Uó«ã$_[kÇ“|ü…~ÅÞ:äÒªëq#ód\Ô>yÙHç¤cåê³€×¶òÈ˜Ð —Úü"¦_x…my¦’ç‡¤€Ïýfqb®lñ,põ±ÚfÕ‚^.0¦
h¸XgyG˜uGƒw¨[pN0&¿T¥²$)ˆ˜‡-BJ1d»ç'&„¦³º:4±W9„xN°áW¨˜cIVg~Ù)Z…ÜWW‡>"þY§-Oç"®øâüTð‹‹²:}Õùçy»ñõùéliø¦tñˆóõU07»ý=„Éôü<±Âÿ|:—‰»´X'rn¾$E½ S##CèC*(\¡=C¨ÌJÔP‹ÁŠåÒç­¬b&hÆFl;Ö,yêcXÚå_°ÎU—‚¶Û·Äô°1ãhˆî:U[ð¶ŸÖÃ#  4˜6ÆÕ½úo¹…ö_˜\æYëð‡Ü±wÛªˆ…£Ô„ÔlUí0˜ˆ2\DÈ-qå²´[z;W¢xØK_îöSž¿/Ž>d(ßò~&&A¢÷7ŒaßIÅ
aò,8Ñù3W|Îä„[ž£)Èa¡Á<ÂÖ
=ŒTÊ2ˆt)Œàp6F¬;.xÇq‘¯ìph§½Çœ®ÄÃ‡C˜¯£6Ö+(E&fy7t•Ã%ú¸P‡‰6ÿ­X;èã!ŽO7çE¶MwNÌÃ6­r4Ü&œÙ¨És¯§CžØ,&&iËçÀ¿‡}s@l=ÖëžÔî›™âÆ¡ì$/Gì‚“Ñ=1¨NTÎ´¨Õfµ"†F™¦´Û°ßÐÛ•Îi!û¹Dñ1ª,:gñb³±â¦·¼zîæÑ¤@2Š
UÎSZ™ÈçG©Ÿˆ|Ø0@Ìó©ÿmŸ<0(ŒâÁ•ÈÄ²rÊ&u¿6ä.-V^yñ xæž¢‡Ã¯QA³"ByÅ<&hÑ–˜çÄ
ã¨KbuþôÁÿ ŒÃï
endstream
```

(Note: There is also some header information before the "stream" word, telling you how long the binary data is, etc.)

What I have been doing is using a `StreamReader` to read the text data, and then I want to switch over and just read the binary data. Something like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(myFile, FileMode.Open))
{
   fs.Seek(250205, SeekOrigin.Begin);  // This jumps to the start of the data above
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
   {
      String line = "";
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != "stream");   // This skips to the end of "stream"

      // I want this to read the 2821 bytes AFTER stream
      byte[] buffer = new byte[2821];
      fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   }
}
```

When I run this, `buffer` does not contain the 2821 bytes after "stream".  Instead, it contains data that is 1024 bytes AFTER the original `Seek()` position.

In other words: I `Seeked` to position 250205. Then, I read a few lines (a total of 57 bytes). But my `buffer` starts at position 251229 (inestead of 250262).

How can I get the `FileStream` to start reading where the `StreamReader` left off?

(My main reason for doing it this way is because `FileStream` does not have a `ReadLine()` method and `StreamReader` does not have a `byte[] = Read()` method.)

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and don't try to use a `StreamReader` with PDF files. Even if pdf contents partially look like a text format, the are not. Thus, you'll only shoot yourself in your foot this way. Study the pdf specification, existing PDF documents, and maybe also other pdf processing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For performance issues, `StreamReader` doesn't read the exact amount of bytes you need into a `Stream` when you call a `Read/ReadLine` method.

It first reads a fixed amount of bytes, stores them into an internal buffer and then gets the bytes you need from that buffer.

When all data stored into the internal buffer have been read, a new `Read` from the same fixed amount is made and so on...

Of course this fixed amount matches the internal buffer size which could be according the  [msdn StreamReader constructor description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This constructor initializes the encoding to UTF8Encoding, the
>   BaseStream property using the stream parameter, and the internal
>   buffer size to 1024 bytes.

So even if your `ReadLine` calls returned a sum of 57 bytes read, at least 1024 has been read from your `FileStream` by your `StreamReader`...

Among others, one solution could be to count the actual read bytes returned by your `ReadLines` calls (by summing line.Length into your loop). And then using this sum variable to `Seek` once again from the beginning of your `Stream` with `fs.Seek(250205 + sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);`.

That being said, i totally agree with what has been said in your question comments. Maybe you will get some surprises by using a `StreamReader` (which is designed to read text) to read a PDF file. For instance, will your `line` length property content always be what is expected, perhaps because of encoding issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get and set the real position from a StreamReader see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22975649/718033